# New senderID does not work on GCM mismatchedSenderID

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

A few months ago I activated my GCM from Google API console and implemented it in my Android project and all worked just fine. I was able to register, get the regId and send notifications from my server using my Server API key. All worked fine.

Yesterday I created a new senderID with my other gmail account, but when I replaced the senderID and server API key with the new information, Google replies the annoying `mismatchedSenderID` error message and the GCM won't be sent!

Nothing else has changed in the project, just a new senderID! What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you replaced the server key on server app?

Comment: If your `senderId` changed, the users must register again for that particular `senderId` in order to receive the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you started sending notifications with the new API Key, all the Registration IDs that were generated for the old senderID will stop working. You should clear your database and start collecting new Registration IDs (based on the new senderID) from your users.

> **Mismatched Sender**
>
> A registration ID is tied to a certain group of senders. When an application registers for GCM usage, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. Make sure you're using one of those when trying to send messages to the device. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration IDs won't work. Happens when error code is MismatchSenderId.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you suggest I "start collecting new registration IDs"? My goal is for the device to call getRegistrationId() with returned id = "". Then the server will store the new registrationId. For this to happen the device must unregister first, but I don't want the device to unregister and reregister every time I run the app. The best solution would be if my server could tell the GCM server to reregister devices with certain old registrationIds... So the problem is how can the device/app know when its registrationId is obsolete (since it belongs to an old senderId).