# New gcmSender value stops all push notifications working

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

We've recently changed the value of the `gcmSender` to point to a different Google Project Number (A switch between the testing and production environments) in the `AirshipConfigOptions` object of the Urban Airship library like so:

```
AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);

options.gcmSender = "123456789101";
```

There were a number of existing registrations to Urban Airship that were registered using the older `gcmSender` value.  With the change, all push notifications to existing devices no longer work.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683874/new-senderid-does-not-work-on-gcm-mismatchedsenderid) indicates that this is because the registrations are tied to a particular sender; however I cannot see any way of removing or forcing re-registration of devices on Urban Airship.

Has anyone encountered this before?  What was the ultimate workaround or fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your app uses the Google APIs to register to GCM (either GoogleCloudMessaging.register or GCMRegistrar.register) or there's some `urbanairship` API that handles the registration.

In either case, Google suggests to re-register a device to GCM every time the application is updated, which in the case of changing the sender would result in a new Registration ID assigned to the device. In their demo they detect it by comparing the current app version to a stored version (which is stored whenever the application gets the registration ID). Since you changed your sender ID, you must have created a new version of your app, which should force the app to re-register to GCM (if you add this suggested logic).

You can see Google's suggested registration code [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

Comment: Great advice; thank you Eran.  For reference `urbanairship` provides an API for registration ([See here for details](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html))